# Select parent view and also make children selected

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `GridLayout` populated with `FrameLayout`s. The `FrameLayout` consists of an `ImageView` and a `TextView`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_home_grid_column_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_home_grid_column_height"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:focusable="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

In code I attach a `OnFocusChangeListener` to frameLayout instance. This instance is fetched using inflator.

```
...
final FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                        .inflate(R.layout.home_grid_item1, homeGrid, false);
final ImageView image = (ImageView) frameLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);
final TextView title = (TextView) frameLayout.findViewById(R.id.title);
...
```

The handler contains a logic:

```
if (hasFocus) {
  if (selectedUrl != null) {
    picasso.load(selectedUrl).into(image);
  } else {
    frameLayout.requestFocus(true);
  }
  //frameLayout.requestFocus();
  //title.requestFocus();
  title.setSelected(true);
} else {
  picasso.load(normalUrl).into(image);

  //frameLayout.clearFocus();
  frameLayout.setSelected(false);
  //title.clearFocus();
  title.setSelected(false);
}
```

While the image is changed as I select items using the d-pad, the background color is not changed according to `StateListDrawable` set to backgrounds:

```
final StateListDrawable rootBgColorList = new StateListDrawable();
rootBgColorList.addState(new int[]{}, new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(homeConfiguration.getGridItemNormalBgColor())));
rootBgColorList.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_selected, android.R.attr.state_focused}, new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(homeConfiguration.getGridItemSelectedBgColor())));
frameLayout.setBackground(rootBgColorList);

final StateListDrawable titleBgColorList = new StateListDrawable();
titleBgColorList.addState(new int[]{}, new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(homeConfiguration.getGridItemTextNormalBgColor())));
titleBgColorList.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_selected, android.R.attr.state_focused}, new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(homeConfiguration.getGridItemTextSelectedBgColor())));
title.setBackground(titleBgColorList);
title.setText(item.getTitle());
title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(homeConfiguration.getGridItemTextColor()));
title.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, homeConfiguration.getGridItemTextSize());
```

Cannot figure out how to make the background selectors fire when I select the frameLayout root view.?